# Data Annotation for Contact form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have this situation:

Model class:

```
public class ContatoModel
{
    private string nome;
    private string email;
    private string telefone;

    public ContatoModel()
    {
    }

    public ContatoModel(string nome, string email, string telefone)
    {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.email = email;
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public string Assunto { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nome Obrigatório")]
    public string Nome
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nome;
        }
        set
        {
            Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "Nome" });
            nome = value;
        }
    }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Obrigatório")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Telefone Obrigatório")]
    public string Telefone { get; set; }

    public string Comentarios { get; set; }
}
```

A View with:

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("EnviarContato", "Contato"))
        {
            <div style="float: left; margin-bottom: 15px;">
                @Html.Label("Assunto")<br />
                @Html.DropDownList("ddlAssunto", assuntos, new {@class="dropdown"})
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
            <div style="float: left; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                @Html.Label("Nome Completo", new { @class = "textfield" })<br />
                @Html.TextBox("txtNome", "", new { @class = "textfield" })
                @Html.ValidationMessage("Nome", "*")
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
            <div style="float: left; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                @Html.Label("Email")<br />
                @Html.TextBox("txtEmail", "", new { @class = "textfield" })
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
            <div style="float: left; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                @Html.Label("Telefone")<br />
                @Html.TextBox("txtTelefone", "", new { @class = "textfield" })
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
            <div style="float: left; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                @Html.Label("Comentários")<br />
                @Html.TextArea("txtComentarios")
            </div>                
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
            <div style="float: left; margin: 2px 20px 0px 255px;">
                @*<input type="image" src="/Content/images/button_send2.gif" />*@
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar" title="Enviar" />
            </div>
        }
```

And this method in controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EnviarContato(FormCollection values)
    {
        try
        {
            string assunto = values["ddlAssunto"];
            string nome = values["txtNome"];
            string email = values["txtEmail"];
            string telefone = values["txtTelefone"];
            string comentarios = values["txtComentarios"];

            model.Assunto = assunto;
            model.Nome = nome;
            model.Email = email;
            model.Telefone = telefone;
            model.Comentarios = comentarios;

            EnviarContato();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { envio = "OK" });
        }
        catch (ValidationException ex)
        {
            throw new ValidationException(ex.Message); //return RedirectToAction("Index", new { envio = "NOK" });
        }
    }
```

I can't do data annotation client works. The ValidationException occurs in server side, but I'd like to see the validation client messages, but it doesn't work. The jQuery files are still loading in my master page.

Another problem is that my view has a combo, loaded by the assunto variable, and I don't know how to include it in validation, to force user select one.

My model class is not for a data entity. It is just to receive form values, to validate and if everything is ok, send the email.

Answer (score 0):

> I cant do data annotation client works. The ValidationException occurs in server side, but I´d like to see the validation client messages, but it doesnt work. The jquery files are still loading in my master page.

1. The files `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` must be included in the page.
2. The `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />` must be in the Web.Config.

> Another problem is that my view has a combo, loaded by the assunto variable, and I dont know how to include it in validation, to force user select one.

One of `Options` with empty value should be in your `DropDownList`. For example "--Select One--".